# Error: UrlError { Unknown URL parameter `ssl-mode' } Rust MySQL

Tags: mysql, rust

I am trying to use SSL in my MySQL Connection String but it is giving me this error
`Error: UrlError { Unknown URL parameter 'ssl-mode' }`
I have referred to official documents from this link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connecting-using-uri-or-key-value-pairs.html.
My connection string looks as follows :

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
let connection_string = format!("mysql://{}:{}@{}?ssl-mode=REQUIRED", &user_name, &password, &hostname);
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
let connection_url: &str = &connection_string;
    let pool = Pool::new(connection_url)?;
    let mut connection = pool.get_conn()?;
```

I am still a rookie in using rust. So please let me know if I am doing something wrong here.

Also if possible please suggest me a better way of approaching.

Thank you !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to encrypt your connection to MySQL with TLS/SSL, you need to create an [`SslOpts`](https://docs.rs/mysql/23.0.0/mysql/struct.SslOpts.html) instance and pass that to the [`OptsBuilder`](https://docs.rs/mysql/23.0.0/mysql/struct.OptsBuilder.html) instance via its [`ssl_opts()`](https://docs.rs/mysql/23.0.0/mysql/struct.OptsBuilder.html#method.ssl_opts) method.

Here is an example how to create an `SslOpts` instance via [`with_danger_accept_invalid_certs()`](https://docs.rs/mysql/23.0.0/mysql/struct.SslOpts.html):

```
let builder = OptsBuilder::new();
let opts = builder
    .ip_or_hostname(Some("..."))
    .db_name(Some("..."))
    .user(Some("..."))
    .pass(Some("..."))
    .ssl_opts(SslOpts::with_danger_accept_invalid_certs(SslOpts::default(), true));
let db_pool = Pool::new_manual(2, 10, opts);
```

Using `with_danger_accept_invalid_certs()` is simple, although, as the name suggests, it might not be the most secure option. It should be much more secure than no encryption at all. Depending on your needs, you might want to take a look at [the other options](https://docs.rs/mysql/23.0.0/mysql/struct.SslOpts.html) provided by the crate.

Comment: I will try this out and let you know thank you very much for your help

Comment: Sorry for replying late, I have tried your method and it works!! Thank you very much for helpling me out, Kind person from the internet :)